# User cannot copy and paste text from div element inside an anchor element

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to copy and paste text from my razor page.

The Index pages are made up of rows filled with details. The rows are nested in hyperlinks so they can be used for navigation purposes. I would like to be able to copy and paste the text from the rows into other documents. My current code won't allow that.

For example, in this JSFiddle project, I can not highlight the phone number and copy and paste it.

https://jsfiddle.net/tL17y08w/

```css
a.index-row,
a.index-row:active,
a.index-row:visited {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.index-row:focus,
a.index-row:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #abcce4;
  color: #000;
}

.index img.profile {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    <a class="index-row" href="#">
      <div class="row row-no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          Dave Thecave
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          (123) 777-1234
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Contoso University
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the CSS property of the anchor `<a>` element to
`user-select: text;`
will allow you to select text with the regular double/triple click.

Unfortunately, this doesn't select the text when you try to drag your mouse though, as the browser still thinks you are trying to move the link somewhere.
On mobile devices, the options for a link already include "copy link text".

Answer (score 1):

You normally *can't* select inside an anchor. (Try selecting your first name above.) It's not really relevant that there's a div in there. You might use JavaScript for the navigation instead.

Note that I've added the [`link` role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role) to the row to maintain some semblance of accessibility.

```js
navRows = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-row');

navRows.forEach(row => {
  row.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.href = row.getAttribute('data-url');
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.index img.profile {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row row-no-gutters nav-row" data-url="#" role="link">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Dave Thecave
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-3">
        (123) 777-1234
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Contoso University
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that we could use `<a>` tag and also copy the text inside `<div>` elements. I noticed that if we omit the `href` attribute from `<a>` tag, then we can select the text inside it. Of course doing that removes the functionality of `<a>` tag, means that you can not navigate to other pages. So I found this solution to return the functionality of `<a>` tag:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("tagId");

const delta = 6;
let startX;
let startY;

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    startX = event.pageX;
    startY = event.pageY;
    element.removeEventListener('click', whenClicked)
});

element.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    const diffX = Math.abs(event.pageX - startX);
    const diffY = Math.abs(event.pageY - startY);

    if (diffX < delta && diffY < delta) {
        element.addEventListener('click', whenClicked);
    } else {
        console.log("dragged")
        element.removeAttribute("href")
    }
});

function whenClicked() {
    console.log("clicked");
    let urlLink = element.getAttribute("data-url");
    element.setAttribute("href", urlLink)
}
```

```css
.index {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.index-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.index-bottom-border {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.index-row {
    /*border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;*/
}

.index-row:first-child {
}

.index-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.index-row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/*.index-row img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
}*/

.index-row .form-control-static {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}


a.index-row,
a.index-row:active,
a.index-row:visited {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.index-row:focus,
a.index-row:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #abcce4;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.index img.profile {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container body-content">
    <a data-url = "about.html" id="tagId" class="index-row">
        <div class="row row-no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                Dave Thecave
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                (123) 777-1234
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Contoso University
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I used a custom attribute called `data-url` that is used to define the url of the page we want to navigate after clicking `<a>` tag. But to distinguish between user mouse drag (to select the text for copy) and **actual click** on the `<a>` tag to navigate to other page, I used the above JavaScript code. The `about.html` that is used for test here is in the same directory of `index.html` and have a dummy code like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>this is about page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```